# Gdata youtube api user feed returns -1

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, youtube-api, gdata

I have been following the youtube tutorial and have gotten the authenticity token as a session length token and stored it in the database. Now when I do

```
String feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";
VideoFeed videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(feedUrl), VideoFeed.class);
System.out.println(videoFeed.getStartIndex());
System.out.println(videoFeed.getXmlBlob().getBlob());
```

`default` is the default user that is authenticated. I recieve -1 for `startindex` and null for the xml blob. Does anyone know the problem?

I can successfully upload a video from the web browser to the authenticated user.

Comment: This has been resolved. It was a factory class interfering with the XML parsing.